# How do I connect AngularJS web application to Oracle database?

Tags: angularjs, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to know how to connect my web application to the oracle database which is written with HTML/CSS and AngularJS.

This is my first web application and I honestly have no idea what I have to do to connect to the oracle database. I've read some material online and it still doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: Did you find it? If so, please write the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) product is included with your Oracle Database, and allows you to publish REST APIs for your database.

It's a java servlet that can run as a standalone application or be plugged into Tomcat.

[image]

You can have a GET handler with some SQL or PL/SQL ran on the backend, and ORDS will send down the response/query results as JSON down to your Angular app.

You can download ORDS from [here](https://oracle.com/rest).

I have a quick video demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAUJmiW1w2Y&list=PL_qNe_aTKkIXN3WW6HOq1O0ENOcH2TcFl&index=3)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a restful API on the Backend side. Then in the Frontend AngularJS app, you could use $resource (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) to interact with the REST api. There are some examples on the documentation. 
There are a lot of tutorials out there on how to use $resource.

Another solution is to use $http which work with any type of Backend apis